# Copy files on windows server using PHP

Tags: php, windows, permissions, plesk

Got a bit of a specific problem here. I'm in the process of developing an automated script in PHP to aid in the creation of a demonstration web application in the event a customer wants a demo site setup.

I'm using a dedicated server running Plesk.

My intention is to create a new sub-domain, create a new database, copy the database from elsewhere, copy the site files from another folder and finally email the customer with their login credentials, etc.

I'm using the Plesk API RPC to create the sub-domain, database and database user which is all working perfectly. I have the database copying the schema from elsewhere and I have the email part working. The only part that is eluding me is the copying of the files from one folder to another.

The source folder is within the same 'httpdocs' folder as the destination folder. The initial problem I had was the open_basedir issue which I've rectified but now I've got the permission denied problem.

I know I can't chmod with windows.
I've tried using xcopy via exec() which returns

```
string(13) "Access denied"
```

I've also tried both cacls and icacls, both of which give me a similar error of

```
string(57) "Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files"
```

Short of giving the whole httpdocs folder write permissions I'm at a bit of a loss on how best to further approach this. Any advice/help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you share what you try to reach with xcopy/icacls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script is works for me:

```
<?php

echo(system('xcopy /Y /Z "C:\Inetpub\vhosts\example.tld\httpdocs\index.html" "C:\Inetpub\vhosts\example.tld\httpdocs\index2.html"'));
```

You can use xcopy:

```
C:\Inetpub\vhosts\example.tld\httpdocs>xcopy index.html index5.html
Does index5.html specify a file name
or directory name on the target
(F = file, D = directory)? F
C:index.html
1 File(s) copied
```

But not in all cases:

```
C:\Inetpub\vhosts\example.tld\httpdocs>xcopy /O index.html index4.html
Does index4.html specify a file name
or directory name on the target
(F = file, D = directory)? F
Access denied
0 File(s) copied
```

Also you can use icacls:

```
C:\Inetpub\vhosts\example.tld\httpdocs>icacls index3.html /grant ftp3:(F)
processed file: index3.html
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

You can even disable inheretence:

```
C:\Inetpub\vhosts\example.tld\httpdocs>icacls index4.html /inheritance:r
processed file: index4.html
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying, as stated I have already tried those methods via PHP they didn't appear to work. I'll give them another try in case it was something I was doing incorrectly and let you know how I get on.

Comment: I've performs this commands under subscription system user(not as Administrator) and from PHP(check script in answer), so there is no any restriction to using xcopy from PHP.

Comment: Whilst I still couldn't get xcopy to work due to access denied, I did manage to take what you had answered and tweek it a little to adjust permissions using icacls before then using xcopy to copy the folders. For anyone trying  to use similar functions please find an example of what I did below;

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my predicament using the following code;

```
    system('icacls "C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.ltd\httpdocs\destination_subdomain" /grant:r "USER_USERNAME":(OI)(CI)F');
    system('xcopy /y /z /e "C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.ltd\httpdocs\source_subdomain" "C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.ltd\httpdocs\destination_subdomain\"');
    system('icacls "C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.ltd\httpdocs\destination_subdomain" /grant:r "USER_USERNAME":(OI)(CI)RX');
```

The first line sets full permissions for the chosen username on the destination folder.

The second line uses xcopy to copy all folders and subfolders, even empty ones from the source folder to the destination folder.

The third line resets the permissions for the destination folder back to read and execute only.